# Current ACS call session list and force to end it by REST

Tags: azure-communication-services

I'm integrating ACS video call into my service (NodeJs backend, React front).

I want to allow ACS video call session only for a scheduled time period, then force to end it if it is over.

However I cannot find the way of implement followings (or REST API)

- list current call sessions
- list participants of each sessions.
- force to stop/end a session by group id or any call ID
- webhooks/callback being called when the session closes and when the participant leaves session.

Could you please give me some hint or advice?

Much appreciated.
Jin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [Call Automation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/communication-services/concepts/voice-video-calling/call-automation-apis) to join or create a new call. Your app can join either as a participant of the call or act out of the call. Each option offers different capabilities described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/communication-services/concepts/voice-video-calling/call-automation-apis#use-cases).

The good news is that both options offer the capability to add and **remove participants** to/from the call:

- [Call Connections - Remove Participant](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/communication/callautomation/call-connections/remove-participant)
- [Server Calls - Remove Participant](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/communication/callautomation/server-calls/remove-participant)

If you decide to use the In-Call (App-Participant) APIs, can you specify the `callbackUri` in the `CreateCallOptions` or `JoinCallOptions`. On this URI, you can listen to events (webhooks) such as [`Participants updated`](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/658dbd4976d088a21f0fc368b6ed42e5688200cd/sdk/communication/Azure.Communication.CallingServer/src/Models/Events/CallingServerEventType.cs) and [deserialize](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/658dbd4976d088a21f0fc368b6ed42e5688200cd/sdk/communication/Azure.Communication.CallingServer/tests/Events/EventTests.cs#L97-L99) the information about them. There is a comprehensive quickstart app available on GitHub showcasing the concept of callback URIs on the call recording capabilities (see the [CallRecordingController.cs](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/communication-services-web-calling-hero/blob/public-preview/Calling/Controllers/CallRecordingController.cs) and [Utils.ts](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/communication-services-web-calling-hero/blob/public-preview/Calling/ClientApp/src/Utils/Utils.ts#L41) in the public-preview branch).

If you decide to use the Out-of-Call APIs, then you need to keep track of the participant IDs yourself.

Currently, the CallingServer SDKs are currently available only for [.NET](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/tree/main/sdk/communication/Azure.Communication.CallingServer) and [Java](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-java/tree/main/sdk/communication/azure-communication-callingserver) so you'll have to use the [REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/communication/callautomation/call-connections).